# Value gets null after posting to laravel from nuxt.js

Tags: php, laravel, post, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt.js frontend that is sending a post request to my laravel backend.
When I send the request I get this response.

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `cars` (`title`, `previewText`, `fuel`, `gearbox`, `brand`, `model`, `year`, `miles`, `price`, `carType`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2019-08-15 13:07:00, 2019-08-15 13:07:00))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

So I guess the controller never recieves the values.

here are the request:

```
  createCar(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  this.isCreatingCar = true
  const formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('title', this.title)
  formData.append('previewText', this.previewText)
  formData.append('fuel', this.fuel)
  formData.append('gearbox', this.gearbox)
  formData.append('brand', this.brand)
  formData.append('model', this.model)
  formData.append('year', this.year)
  formData.append('miles', this.miles)
  formData.append('price', this.price)

  $.each(this.imageList, function(key, image) {
    formData.append(`images[${key}]`, image)
  })

  this.$axios.post('/create_car', { data: formData }).then(res => {
    this.status = true
    this.isCreatingCar = false
  })
},
```

the function in the controller:

```
public function createCar(Request $request) {

        $title = $request->title;
        $previewText = $request->previewText;
        $fuel = $request->fuel;
        $gearbox = $request->gearbox;
        $brand = $request->brand;
        $model = $request->model;
        $year = $request->year;
        $miles = $request->miles;
        $price = $request->price;
        $carType = $request->carType;
        $images = $request->images;

        $car = Car::create([
            'title' => $title,
            'previewText' => $previewText,
            'fuel' => $fuel,
            'gearbox' => $gearbox,
            'brand' => $brand,
            'model' => $model,
            'year' => $year,
            'miles' => $miles,
            'price' => $price,
            'carType' => $carType
        ]);

        // store each image
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $imagePath = Storage::disk('uploads')->put('/cars' . '/' . $car->id, $image);
            carImage::create([
                'carImageCaption' => $title,
                'carImagePath' => 'uploads' . $imagePath,
                'carId' => $car->id
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json(['errors' => false, 'data' => $car]);
    }
```

Here is the form:

```
      <form @submit.prevent="createCar">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Titel</label>
          <input
            v-model="title"
            class="form-control"
            required
            :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.title }"
            placeholder="Titel"
          />
          <div v-if="errors.title" class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ errors.title[0] }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Beskrivning</label>
          <textarea
            v-model="previewText"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Beskrivning"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bränsle</label>
          <b-form-select v-model="fuel" class="mb-3 form-control">
            <option value="Bensin">Bensin</option>
            <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
            <option value="El">El</option>
            <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
          </b-form-select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Växellåda</label>
          <b-form-select v-model="gearbox" class="mb-3 form-control">
            <option value="Automat">Automat</option>
            <option value="Manuell">Manuell</option>
          </b-form-select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Märke</label>
          <input
            v-model="brand"
            class="form-control"
            required
            :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.brand }"
            placeholder="Märke"
          />
          <div v-if="errors.brand" class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ errors.brand[0] }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Modell</label>
          <input
            v-model="model"
            class="form-control"
            required
            :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.model }"
            placeholder="Modell"
          />
          <div v-if="errors.model" class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ errors.model[0] }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Årsmodell</label>
          <input v-model="year" class="form-control" type="number" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Miltal</label>
          <input v-model="miles" class="form-control" type="number" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Pris</label>
          <input
            v-model="price"
            class="form-control"
            required
            :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.price }"
            type="number"
          />
          <div v-if="errors.price" class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ errors.price[0] }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <b-form-file
            v-model="imageList"
            placeholder="Välj fil.."
            drop-placeholder="Släpp filen här.."
            multiple
          ></b-form-file>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Lägg till"
            class="btn btn-default w-100"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
```

Tell me if I can provide with something else!

I'm totally new to PHP, so I not very familiar with debugging in php or even finding the source of the problem.

I've been programming mostly .net so be gentle with me :D

Edit: I've noticed that the problem seems to be with the POST request get treated as an GET

error: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: `var_dump($title)`? Maybe show your form, and also perhaps show where formData is coming from.

Comment: Can you console.log(formData); in axios promise block?

Comment: Can you `dd($request->all());` to see what you get in request?

Comment: I updated the question, what does dd and var_dump do? I run the server on Xampp

Comment: It looks like formData is empty even before the request

Comment: `dd` will display your request, if you got data inside it's problem in Laravel if you didn't, something is wrong on frontend.

Comment: The data is in the formData, in the frontend

Comment: Try to change `const formData` to `let formData`, and also before that `console.log(this.title)` or something to see do you have data in variable.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my comment, i noticed that the formData do indeed get populated correctly. So the issue seems to be in the backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197987/discussion-between-mare96-and-littlemygler).

Answer (score 2):

If you got data in your request (you can check with `dd($request->all());`), you probably didn't set in your model your `$fillable` fields.

If that is reason you can read more about [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Good luck!